# Changing the input font color with readonly problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to change the font color of a disabled input. Since it's gray when it's disabled, I want it to appear black. Therefore, I tried to use readonly, but it did not work and now the input doesn't show what it's supposed to. It just says [object Object]. Here is my HTML and TS code. What might be the problem?

HTML code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="50" class="pr-4">
                                <mat-label>Producer</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="Producer" readonly="readonly">
                                <mat-icon matSuffix class="disabled-text">short_text</mat-icon>
                                <mat-error>Producer is Mandatory!</mat-error>
                            </mat-form-field>
```

TS code:

```
 Producer: new FormControl(
                {
                    value:
                        this.order.ProducerSellerCode +
                        "-" +
                        this.order.ProducerSellerName,
                    readonly: true,
                },
                [Validators.required]
            ),
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your css?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is showing [object Object] is because you are setting a js object to your input field.

If you want to change the color of a readonly input, the following css can be used:

```
input:read-only {
  color: black;
}
//OR
input[readonly] {
  color: black;
}
```

Change input to a class name if you wish to only apply this to a select element.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added that to the css file but it didn't change.

Comment: @HecticPlatypus Have you confirmed the css is being applied using inspector?